# C# BackgroundWorker update UI from DoWork event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I know that the UI can only be updated from the main thread; but why can I update a StatusStrip Label within my **DoWork** event? but when I try to update another control, the program throws a cross thread exception (as expected).

And since this is possible, is it a good idea/practice update this label from within event?

Here's my code:

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_WorkCompleted;
    }

   private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "foo";
    }
```

Comment: ToolStrip items don't come from Controls.  Just because it didn't throw an exception doesn't mean it's a good idea.  Just don't access gui components in the DoWork method.

Comment: First off not all properties of a control are unsafe from accessing from another thread. For example `Control.Tag`. Second, as LarsTech said, just because you can doesn't mean you should. It will bite you someday.

Comment: What if I use the beginInvok method? Or is never a good idea do this?

Comment: My guess it that your `toolStripStatusLabel1` has been created in worker thread, not UI thread. The rule states that, UI controls can be accessed only from within the thread they were created on.